# Apache camel to consolidate many web service responses into one

Tags: web-services, response, apache-camel, consolidation

I'm new to Apache Camel and I have to achieve the specific functionality. Have to send many requests to an external WebSevice and to consolidate the responses into one big response. In this specific task I have to decide when to stop calling the external webservice based on the specific tag in the responses content.

**Any idea on how this could be implemented in Camel?**

Comment: Is it a fixed request? What is the source of your request. Any more details will help.

Answer (score 0):

for your problem, I think the [aggregator](http://camel.apache.org/aggregator.html) is the solution.